# is there a css' line-height in LaTeX?

Tags: css, latex

Do you know a way to influence the line-height (distance between the lines inside a pragraph) in LaTeX? I can't find anything.

I want lines to have more space than the default.

Comment: Don't know LaTeX, but the CSS 2.1 spec says the concept of the "strut" (that applies a minimal value for the line height) is borrowed from TeX. That suggests that what your looking for is a [strut, like this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts)

Comment: In LaTeX, this distance is given by `\baselineskip`. Load the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) and use something like `\onehalfspacing` or `\doublespacing`, or set it manually using `\setstretch{2}` (say).

Comment: This was the answer Werner! Multi thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Put

```
\linespread{1.15}
```

in the preamble.